# Freetype2 not rendering font correctly

Tags: c++, text, freetype, freetype2

I'm having some issues using freetype2 rendering text, adapting it from using SDL_ttf previously.

The code below results in the following image:

[image]

Clearly not the DejaVu Sans font that it's set to, but unfortunately I'm at a loss to what's going wrong.

I think the code is mostly self-explanatory - blit_rect.address is the destination buffer

```
/**
 * Blit text to the screen.
 * @param text Text to display.
 * @param colour Colour of the text.
 * @param xpos Absolute horizontal position at the display.
 * @param ypos Absolute vertical position at the display.
 * @param width Available width of the text (in pixels).
 * @param align Horizontal alignment of the string.
 */
void VideoSystem::BlitText(const uint8 *text, uint32 colour, int xpos, int ypos, int width, Alignment align)
{
    this->blit_rect.ValidateAddress();

    int w, h;
    this->GetTextSize(text, &w, &h);
    ypos += h;
    int real_w = std::min(w, width);
    switch (align) {
        case ALG_LEFT:
            break;

        case ALG_CENTER:
            xpos += (width - real_w) / 2;
            break;

        case ALG_RIGHT:
            xpos += width - real_w;
            break;

        default: NOT_REACHED();
    }

    bool use_kerning = FT_HAS_KERNING(this->face);
    uint previous = 0;
    FT_GlyphSlot slot = this->face->glyph;

    for (const uint8 *pt = text; *pt != '\0';) {
        uint32 u32;
        int len = DecodeUtf8Char(pt, strlen((const char *)pt), &u32);
        if (len == 0) break;
        pt += len;

        uint glyph = FT_Get_Char_Index(this->face, u32);

        if (use_kerning && previous && glyph) {
            FT_Vector delta;
            FT_Get_Kerning(this->face, previous, glyph, FT_KERNING_DEFAULT, &delta);
            xpos += delta.x >> 6;
        }

        if (FT_Load_Glyph(this->face, glyph, FT_LOAD_RENDER) != 0) {
        }

        uint32 *dest = this->blit_rect.address + (xpos + slot->bitmap_left) + (ypos - slot->bitmap_top) * this->blit_rect.pitch;
        for (int i = 0; i < slot->bitmap.rows; i++) {
            if (ypos - slot->bitmap_top + i < 0) continue;
            for (int j = 0; j < slot->bitmap.pitch; j++) {
                if (xpos + slot->bitmap_left + j < 0) continue;
                if (slot->bitmap.buffer[i * slot->bitmap.pitch + j] > 0) {
                    dest[i * this->blit_rect.pitch + j] = slot->bitmap.buffer[i * slot->bitmap.pitch + j];
                }
            }
        }

        previous = glyph;
        xpos += slot->advance.x >> 6;
        ypos += slot->advance.y >> 6;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Font is loaded with:

```
/* Freetype init */
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&this->library) != 0) {
}

if (FT_New_Face(this->library, font_name, 0, &this->face) != 0) {
}

/** @todo use actual screen dpi? */
if (FT_Set_Char_Size(this->face, 0, font_size * 64, 0, 0) != 0) {
}
```

EDIT2:
adding `FT_Render_Glyph(slot, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);` (or `FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO`) after the FT_Load_Glyph does nothing.

Any other comments about the quality appreciated, of course

Comment: A bit small, that size. Shouldn't you try with antialiasing enabled?

Comment: Looks like no hinting is being applied at all.

Comment: How does one apply hinting/antialiasing?

Comment: @LordAro if I knew that I would leave an answer instead of a comment, sorry. I know that there are patent restrictions on using the hints that are built into a Truetype font (if they haven't expired yet), but I thought they had effective ways around that.

Comment: One checks the library documentation. I suspect you have to set a  [`FT_RENDER_MODE`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Render_Mode) first.

Comment: my issue with that assessment is that i'm largely emulating sdl_ttf, and doesn't appear to do that, unless i'm missing something... https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/file/b773c1cd55a2/SDL_ttf.c#l1343

Comment: The image that you provide seems to be symptomatic of a bad blending function. It's likely that the font is being rendered correctly, but is not being blended with the background correctly. Look into your blending function and see if that's the issue.

Comment: The "blending function" is provided - see the line beginning `uint32 *dest = ...` and the for loops. What else should I be doing? I don't really understand the "format" that freetype returns

Comment: There could be any number of problems here, without seeing the rendering code. That said, if the problem is in your loop have you considered trying FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap to give you the bitmap data? I ask because your for loop looks crazy complex.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rendering code"? Other than what you can see here, it's just a basic push mem array to SDL_Texture, then push that to screen. I don't see how that's an issue, as all non-text works fine